# Change character case at specific position in java

Tags: java

Write a program that accepts a string and two integers from user. It then changes the case of characters at those indices as specified by two integers entered by the user.

Eg:

```
String = "ProgRaMinG";
int n1=3;
int n2=5;
```

Result should be PrOgraMinG

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please do not edit out the only detail in your question, you should be adding more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Character class Methods:**
*isDigit(ch)*               Returns true if the specified character is a digit.
*isLetter(ch)*             Returns true if the specified character is a letter.
*isLetterOfDigit(ch)*  Returns true if the specified character is a letter or digit.
*isLowerCase(ch)*    Returns true if the specified character is a lowercase letter.
*isUpperCase(ch)*    Returns true if the specified character is an uppercase letter.
*toLowerCase(ch)*    Returns the lowercase of the specified character.
*toUpperCase(ch)*    Returns the uppercase of the specified character.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        int n1 = sc.nextInt();
        int n2 = sc.nextInt();
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(s);
        n1--;/*as string is "Zero" index based*/
        n2--;
        /*changing character as n1 position*/
        if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(n1)))  //return true if UpperCase
            str.setCharAt(n1,Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(n1)));
        else
            str.setCharAt(n1,Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(n1)));
        /*changing character as n2 position*/
        if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(n1)))  //return true if UpperCase
            str.setCharAt(n2,Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(n2)));
        else
            str.setCharAt(n2,Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(n2)));
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```